# I want to paste the pivot table from sheet two in another workbook as a range, but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

```
Sub pivot()
Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, apwb As Workbook, apws As Worksheet, LastRow As Integer
Set apwb = Workbooks.Open("F:\My Documents - Disk C\Victor\VBA\Paste\Paste.xlsx")
Set apws = apwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

        With pt
            .ColumnGrand = False
            .RowGrand = False
            .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
            .PivotFields("City").Orientation = xlHidden
            .PivotFields("Product").Orientation = xlRowField

        End With
        For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
            pf.Subtotals(1) = False
        Next pf


        pt.PivotSelect "", xlData, True
        Selection.Copy
        apws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next pt
Next ws
End Sub
```

The code doesn't modify the Paste.xlsx file at all. What should I change in my code? I have a medium understanding of VBA.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try change code below:

```
   pt.PivotSelect "", xlData, True
   Selection.Copy
   apws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To:

```
   pt.TableRange1.Copy
   apws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: But if you have more than 1 pivottable, cannot keep paste at cell(1,1).

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the correction you made did not work. I only have 1 pivot table but 2 sheets. Is this the reason it is not working? Thanks

Comment: You should has total 2 pivot tables (1 for 2 sheets)? Right? But both will paste at same location at Sheet1. Can you program paste last pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set apwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Lee Li Fong\Desktop\Website\Book2.xlsx")
Set apws = apwb.Worksheets("Sheet6")
C = 1

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.PivotTables.Count > 0 Then    'Only copy sheet have pivot table
        ws.PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Copy
        apws.Cells(1, C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        C = C + 5   'next paste to other column
    End If
Next
```